# is there a way to automatically embed YouTube videos when the're uploaded?

Tags: html, css

I understand that you can manually embed them using the built-in share function, but I'm wondering if I could do something where when I upload a video, it automatically becomes embedded on my personal website. `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kFLzGAjSJNI"></iframe>` does work, it would just add something else to do when I upload or stream.

Comment: can you further explain your request/question please? I don't understand clearly. Thank you

Comment: So, I have a YouTube channel, and I'm currently working on making a website. I occasionally upload gaming videos/streams. I have a page for my videos and streams, and I manually embed them to the page. I'm wondering if there's some kind of script that embeds the videos automatically when I upload them to YouTube.

Comment: Are you using Wordpress or otherwise, what framework do you use? Or is it plain html/css custom code. I know a plugin but it's for WP.

Comment: Just plain html/css. I would also be open to using another programming language to run a script for it.

Comment: hmm can't find anything sorry. The closest I found is something like this https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Lightweight-Youtube-Video-Gallery-with-jQuery-SpidocheTube.html but I don't think that's what you want. It's going to have to be custom! :) good luck

Comment: That's not what I was looking for, but I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sure np i took some time to look for it as I could have used the same kind of script :)